# Building last version Glade

Tags: build, gtk3, glade

due to problems in the glade packaged for Ubuntu. I decided to build the latest version (3.20). I also had to compile the gtk + 3.20. Then I realized that some components were strangers.

[image]

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is my gtk theme :-\

[image]